# A metric on $\mathbb {P(N)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I want to prove that $(\mathbb{P(N)},d)$ is a metric space where $\mathbb{P(N)}$ is the power set of $\mathbb{N}$.  And $d:\mathbb{P(N)}\times \mathbb{P(N)} \mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$d(A,B)=\begin{cases} 0, & \text{if A} \Delta \text{B=}\emptyset  \\ m^{-1}, & \text{where m is the smallest member of} A\Delta B \end{cases} $.

How to approach this problem?I saw the solution but it does not look much intuitive?Can someone suggest me some intuitive solution of this problem.

Comment: Verify the axioms ? The only not trivial is the 3rd one.

Comment: Regarding "the 3rd one", a hint is given on p. 8 (Example 1.1.16) of [these notes](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kaguilar/MAT472/metric_spaces_k_aguilar_c.pdf) by Konrad Aguilar.

Comment: You need to let $\Bbb N$ have minimum $1$ here, of course.

Comment: I find it intuitive to write $d(A,B)=f(A\bigtriangleup B),$ where $f(S)=0$ if $S=\varnothing$ and $f(S)=m^{-1}$ if $S\ne\varnothing$ and $m$ is the smallest member of $S,$ and use the facts (1) $\bigtriangleup$ is a group operation (as is seen using characteristic functions), its identity is $\varnothing,$ and every set is its own inverse, and (2) $f(U)\leqslant f(V)$ for $U\subseteq V,$ and $f(S\cup T) = \max\{f(S),f(T)\},$ so the ultrametric inequality for $d$ follows by writing $S=A\bigtriangleup B$ and $T=B\bigtriangleup C,$ and using $A\bigtriangleup C=S\bigtriangleup T\subseteq S\cup T.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A \Delta B = \emptyset$ iff $A = B$ as sets: recall that

$$A \Delta B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$$

so $A=B$ implies that both set differences are empty and so is their union, and if $A \Delta B= \emptyset$ then both $A \setminus B = \emptyset$ (so $A \subseteq B$) and $B \setminus A=\emptyset$ (so $B \subseteq A$) and combined we have $A=B$ again. So this basic set theory fact plus the definition of $d$ says $$d(A,B)=0 \iff A=B$$

Also by the definition of $A\Delta B$ it's clear that $A \Delta B = B \Delta A$ (as we just swap the sets in the union) and so as we take the 1 over the minimum of the same set (in the non-empty case, otherwise both terms are $0$ anyway), clearly

$$d(A,B)=d(B,A)$$

As to the triangle inequality: first note that for sets $A,B,C$ we have

$$A \Delta B \subseteq (A \Delta C) \cup (C \Delta B)\tag{1}$$

Proof: if $x \in A \Delta B$, say $x \in A$, $x \notin B$, there are two cases: $x \in C$ (in which case $x \in C\setminus B \subseteq C \Delta B$) or $x \notin C$ (and then $x \in A \setminus C \subseteq A \Delta C$), and in both cases we're done. When $x \notin A,x \in B$ we use the same distinction to show the inclusion.

So for the triangle inequality we can assume WLOG we have three distinct sets $A,B,C \subseteq \Bbb N$ and if we define $m_1=\min(A \Delta C)$ and $m_2 = \min(C \Delta B)$, then $\min(A \Delta B)$ is a member of $A \Delta C$ or of $C \Delta B$, by $(1)$ and so $m_1 \le \min(A \Delta B)$ or $m_2 \le \min(B \Delta C)$ or 
by taking the inverses $d(A,B) \le \frac{1}{m_1} = d(A,C)$ or $d(A,B)\le \frac{1}{m_2}=d(C,B)$ and in either case

$$d(A,B) \le \max(d(B,C),d(C,B)) \le d(B,C) + d(C,B)$$

showing that $d$ is even an [ultrametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space) on $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$